# What is causing this glitch?

Tags: actionscript-3

I am currently coding a game, and have encountered an annoying glitch. Occasionally, when you kill an enemy in game, it will drop extra currency, and another enemy onscreen will be removed from the enemylist. However, this second enemy, the one removed from the enemylist, will still be on screen, and will still shoot at the player. Below are code snippets from the collision formula, the enemies destruction sequence, and the bullet hitcheck sequence.

Collision formula:

```
    public function testCollision(enemy:Entity):Boolean{
        var eX:Number = enemy.collision.xPos
        var eY:Number = enemy.collision.yPos
        var eSL:Number = enemy.collision.SideLength/2
        if(eX-xPos<(SideLength/2)+eSL && eY-yPos<(SideLength/2)+eSL && eX-xPos>-(SideLength/2)-eSL && eY-yPos>-(SideLength/2)-eSL){
            return true
        }else{
            return false
        }
    }
```

Enemy destruction sequence:

```
        if(deathVar){
            view.transparency -= 1/20
            if(view.transparency<0.1){
                var cur = new PixelCurrency(2)
                cur.collision.xPos = collision.xPos
                cur.collision.yPos = collision.yPos
                entityCreated.dispatch(cur)
                destroy()
            }
        }
```

Bullet hitcheck:

```
        for each (var enemy:Entity in Game.entities){
            if(enemy.allies == Pixapocalypse.EnemyFaction){
                if(collision.testCollision(enemy)){
                    if(enemy.life){
                        enemy.life.changeHealth(-2)
                        this.sound.playSound(new basicHitSound())
                        this.destroy()
                        break
                    }
                    else{

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

If you need any extra info, please tell me, I am greatly appreciative of your help.

Comment: How do you control contents in `Game.entities`? Please add code that performs management on this collection. Most likely the trouble is forward lookup plus splicing PLUS doing something with the handler along with splicing.

Comment: @Vesper: What do you mean by control contents, if you mean addition and subtraction of entities from the vector, then that is done by `entities.push(entity)`, `splice(indexOf(entity))`, and in a special case, `entities.length = 0`, the ordering on entities in the vector isn't changed, entities are just added and removed. If you meant something else, just let me know!

Comment: Yes, I've meant exactly this. Note that `splice()` has 2 mandatory arguments, if the second one is omitted, the entire array tail is dropped off the array! So, you might have worse bugs in your code than you've discovered. Please post this part of code.

Comment: @Vesper, The line of code which actually splices the entities is this: `entities.splice(entities.indexOf(entity), 1)`, I always screw up the splice command when writing it, but at least Flash catches me! However, I am inclined to believe that the problem lies with the 'Pixapocalypse.EnemyFaction' vector, as currency should not be automatically created on destruction, and extra currency appears when the glitch occurs.

Comment: See, if you are using a `for (var i:int=0;i<entities.length;i++)` to iterate through your array, and you splice within this cycle, the element that's right after the one being spliced is not processed. Another nitpick is that you don't check if `indexOf()` returns a valid value, which can too occur under special conditions with a flawed code.

Comment: I may have had an idea about what is causing this glitch, I will get back to you in a couple days after trying the fix

Comment: Glitch is fixed, problem resolved, thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 0):

What happens when Enemy.life < 0 ?

Comment: Unless you are answering a question, you should put any comments as comments to the respective posts (i.e. this should have been a comment to the question, not its own answer)

Comment: Yes, I know, but I'm unable to convert this answer to comment after I added it by mistake. Althought I think there might be something wrong inside else part of the if(enemy.life) statement because that is where the enemy should die.

Comment: The `if(enemy.life)` checks to see whether the enemy has a life property at all, that is to say does it have health, or is it just an object, weapon, etc.

Comment: So enemy can only loose life when he still has it. The dying algorytm is triggered by changeHealth. Please edit your post with that algorytm with it's interface.

Comment: no, this function checks to see whether an entity in `Pixapocalypse.EnemyFaction` actually has a health component at all, as adding a health component is optional. This does not check whether the enemy has life remaining, that is done within the life component itself. I have confirmed that the life component works, and I think that it is unrelated to this problem.